# Dynamic overview of dropdown choice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'd like to have a dynamic result as consequence of a drop-down choice in my website. I have the following example with cars. Buying a volvo should result in car costs ar 1000 for example. I'd like to have this real time, depending on the dropdown choice that is made.

Could you help me with this? I think it must be some kinde of javascript, but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
    #choice {
        float: right;
    }
</style>
<form action="action_page.php">
    <select name="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="choice">
    Car costs are: Result of choice
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: So you are not fetching the details from mysql and only want to display a sample data according to the selected option?

Comment: Yes, correct. I do not use any sql with this website

Comment: make ajax call and fetch option and show them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work just fine.

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script>
            function Car($scope) {
                $scope.car = {

                    'Volvo': {
                     'Volvo-2000': ['Volvo-2000'],
                        'Volvo-3000': ['Volvo-3000']
                    },
                    'Saab': {
                     'Saab-2000': ['Saab-2000'],
                        'Saab-3000': ['Saab-3000']

                    },
                    'Fiat': {
                     'Fiat-2000': ['Fiat-2000'],
                        'Fiat-3000': ['Fiat-3000']
                    },
                    'Audi': {
                        'AUDI-2000': ['AUDI-2000'],
                        'AUDI-3000': ['AUDI-3000']
                    }
                };
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div ng-controller="Car">
            <div>
                Car:
                <select id="car" ng-model="price" ng-options="car for (car, price) in car">
                    <option value=''>Select</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                Price: <select id="price" ng-disabled="!car" ng-model="price" ng-options="car for (car,price) in price"><option value=''>Select</option></select>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpdrx7L7/3/)

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the misconception, this should be just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
#choice{ float:right;}
</style>
<script>       
 var changeInput = function  (val){
            var input = document.getElementById("choice");
            input.value = val;
        }
</script>


<form action="action_page.php">
<select name="cars" onchange = 'changeInput(this.value);'>
<option value="volvo 121">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab 121">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat 121">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi 121">Audi</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<div>
Car cost: 
<form>
<input type = "text" id = "choice" value = "" style="float: left;">
</form>
</div>    


</body>
</html>
```

[2nd Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40vd1xbu/)

Comment: This was not what I meant. I need to have a textual representation of the choice in the div next to the choice

Comment: @Richard Oops. Give me a moment!